# How to prevent Vue Snotify confirm from showing multiple instances

Tags: vue.js, snotify

I'm pretty new to Vue and Snotify, so please forgive the newb question.  I've scanned the docs, and nothing jumps out at me.

Here's the deal: I have a Vue component that deletes files, using a Snotify confirm box.  Like this:

```
destroy() {
    this.$snotify.confirm('', 'Delete File?', {
      buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Yes',
                action: (toast) => {
                    axios.delete([API endpoint])
                    .then(response => {
                        // destroy the vue listeners, etc
                        this.$destroy();

                        // remove the element from the DOM
                        this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el);
                    });
                    this.$snotify.remove(toast.id);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'No',
                action: (toast) => {
                    this.$snotify.remove(toast.id)
                }
            }
        ]
    })
}
```

The problem is that if you click the "Delete" button a second time, another "Delete File?" confirmation appears above the first.  Expected behavior is that the second click make the confirmation go away.
[image]

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`this.$snotify.confirm()` returns the toast info, which includes an ID that could be passed to [`this.$snotify.remove()`](https://artemsky.github.io/vue-snotify/documentation/api/snotify.html#remove) for removal:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    destroy() {
      if (this._toast) {
        this.$snotify.remove(this._toast.id, true /* immediate */)
      }

      this._toast = this.$snotify.confirm('', 'Delete File?', {/*...*/})
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/removing-a-vue-snotify-toast-kqcc1?file=/src/App.vue:240-340)

Comment: That absolutely worked!  Thank you so much!